# Adding a new root view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I'm developing an IOS Application where I have a login page. When the user opens the app for the first time I want the "login" page to appear in the very beginning.

Once the user is logged in I want to change root and assign it to the "MainViewController" (Where the user comes after the login is done)

The reason why I want to do this is because I want to clear the back stack in the application frequently.

Now the problem is.. When I tap the logout button the app should navigate to the login page again. How can I accomplish this in a good way?

Is there any way I can clear back stack without going back to root controller?

Any input would be much appreciated.

**SigninViewController**

```
    func navigateToMain(){
    if let storyboard = storyboard{
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabViewController") as! TabViewController

        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController = vc

        self.present(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

What can I do in the logout method to navigate back to login and clear the back stack?

Comment: You can change rootview controller to 'Login' screen.

Comment: When I press the login button?

Comment: No, when you press logout button. change the rootviewcontroller to 'Login' screen.

Comment: @ChamanSharma Oh my bad. I mean logout button of course. :) Thanks, I'll try this.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the login view controller as the root view controller when the user press logout. When you change root view controller, all the previous navigation stacks are cleared.

you can use this code for a fade in animation to change root view controller.

```
    func makeRootVC(storyBoardName : String, vcName : String) {
    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: storyBoardName, bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    nav.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    self.window?.rootViewController = nav
    let options: UIView.AnimationOptions = .transitionCrossDissolve
    let duration: TimeInterval = 0.6
    UIView.transition(with: self.window!, duration: duration, options: options, animations: {}, completion: nil)
}
```

Note: copy this function in your Appdelegate.swift file and then in your viewcontroller, you can use it like this:

```
@IBAction func logoutBtnPressed(_ sender : Any) { 
  let appDelegateObj = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
  appDelegateObj.makeRootVC(storyboardName: "Main", vcName : "YourLoginVC")
}
```